# Joining to a table multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have three tables: `Account`, `Management`, and `ManagementAccountLookup`.

The Account table contains *locations*.  The Management table contains *records for every level in the business hierarchy*.  The Management table also contains a value (*LevelID)* that indicates which level in the hierarchy the record falls in.  The ManagementAccountLookup table is the lookup table that connects them.

I'm having trouble writing a query to get all the accounts with two of their associated management records.

For example: an Account might have 5 or more management records associated to it, but I only care about two specific managements with a levelID of Brand or Region. Also, I only want an account to show up once in the result grid.

The result set should look something like this:

```
AccountID   Brand      Region
---------   --------   ------
account1    Wendys     East US
account2    McDonalds  West US
```

This seems like a simple problem, but I haven't been able to figure out exactly how to get that result.  I have tried self-joins, subqueries, and everything else I could think of, but I can't seem to get the results into a single row.

Any help would be appreciated.

*EDIT:
ManagementAccountLookup has two fields (AccountID, ManagementID).  Those are the PKs of the two other tables.
Management has a column LevelID which is how you can tell if the record is a Brand, Region, District, etc...

The Brand and Region will be two separate rows in the Management table. I need the result grid to have them in the same row.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the schema of the table. We want to help you, but we don't know what to fields to join

Comment: Sorry, I should have done that, I just didn't want to make my question more confusing by adding a bunch of unnecessary data. I made an edit to make it slightly easier to understand the table structure.  Thanks for the input, I'll keep it in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add ManagementAccountLookup/Management combination twice to get informations in one row. I've put `LevelID` criteria directly in join to ease up on possible transition to left-joins if need arises.

```
select Account.AccountID,
       m_brand.Name Brand,
       m_region.Name Region
  from Account
 inner join ManagementAccountLookup mal_brand
    on Account.AccountID = mal_brand.AccountID
 inner join Management m_brand
    on mal_brand.ManagementID = m_brand.ManagementID
   and m_brand.LevelID = @Insert_Management_Brand_Level_Here
 inner join ManagementAccountLookup mal_region
    on Account.AccountID = mal_region.AccountID
 inner join Management m_region
    on mal_region.ManagementID = m_region.ManagementID
   and m_region.LevelID = @Insert_Management_Region_Level_Here
```

**EDIT:** if you need to show all accounts you can use combination of left/inner join in parentheses:

```
select Account.AccountID,
       m_brand.Name Brand,
       m_region.Name Region
  from Account
  left join 
  (
       ManagementAccountLookup mal_brand
       inner join Management m_brand
         on mal_brand.ManagementID = m_brand.ManagementID
        and m_brand.LevelID = @Insert_Management_Brand_Level_Here
 )
   on Account.AccountID = mal_brand.AccountID
 left join 
 (
       ManagementAccountLookup mal_region
       inner join Management m_region
          on mal_region.ManagementID = m_region.ManagementID
         and m_region.LevelID = @Insert_Management_Region_Level_Here
 )
    on Account.AccountID = mal_region.AccountID
```

To make it a bit more readable you might employ CTE:

```
; with mal_level as (
  select AccountID,
         m.LevelID,
         m.Name
    from ManagementAccountLookup mal
   inner join Management m
      on mal.ManagementID = m.ManagementID
)
select Account.AccountID,
       m_brand.Name Brand,
       m_region.Name Region
  from Account
  left join mal_level m_brand
    on Account.AccountID = m_brand.AccountID
   and m_brand.LevelID = @Insert_Management_Brand_Level_Here
  left join mal_level m_region
    on Account.AccountID = m_region.AccountID
   and m_region.LevelID = @Insert_Management_Region_Level_Here
```

Or [outer apply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
select Account.AccountID,
       b.Brand,
       r.Region
  from Account
 outer apply
 (
       select m_brand.Name Brand
         from ManagementAccountLookup mal_brand
        inner join Management m_brand
           on mal_brand.ManagementID = m_brand.ManagementID
          and m_brand.LevelID = @Insert_Management_Brand_Level_Here
        where mal_brand.AccountID = Account.AccountID
 ) b
 outer apply
 (
       select m_region.Name Region
         from ManagementAccountLookup mal_region
        inner join Management m_region
           on mal_region.ManagementID = m_region.ManagementID
          and m_region.LevelID = @Insert_Management_Region_Level_Here
        where mal_region.AccountID = Account.AccountID
 ) r
```

Comment: Awesome!  That looks like it's working.  I'll do some more testing tomorrow to make sure, but I think that is what I need.  Also, thanks for guessing on the table structure to provide pretty much copy-and-paste code for me to test.  I had tried something similar to this, but I had joined to the ManagementAccountLookup table once and the Management table twice from there.  That was where I was getting hung up.

Comment: I have another question about this statement.  If I needed to allow Accounts to show up in the grid even if they don't have a Region or a Brand associated, how would I go about that?  I can't just change the joins to left joins because that produces a lot of duplicates. The only way I've come up with (which isn't pretty) is to union the results to another query off all the accounts with no management.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Justin Sorry for the delay, I was off yesterday. Please check my renewed answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm kicking myself for not figuring out that all I was missing from the first query was parenthesis. I ended up creating a view yesterday that essential does what your CTE does. I hadn't ever seen that done before, but I like it more than the view that I created.  I had never seen the outer apply method before either.    Thanks a lot for your help, I learned a lot from it.  (also, I made a slight edit to your answer because the apply wouldn't work without putting an 'as something' after the parenthesis.  Apparently, my edit has to be reviewed before they will post it though).